# How to prevent String values read from resources to be shown as hardcoded in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio shows string read from the resources to be hardcoded for example

```
     String defaultPort = c.getString(R.string.default_port);
```

is shown as

```
     String defaultPort = "4566";
```

Even though it highlights the constant string and when clicked it expands and shows the real code, this confuses me very often as if I have hard coded my string, I need to disable it.

Comment: This is quite a cool feature, tho :)

Comment: Depends what you prefer. I want to see real code not values and often this can be misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu: File | Settings

Category: Editor | General

Section: Code Folding

Uncheck "Android String References"

Comment: Yes, thanks I figured it out, but need to restart android studio for it to take effect.

Comment: Hmmm... I just had to close and reopen the source code file in the editor.

Comment: Yes, that may have been enough, but it's wierd it doesnt apply immediately